# anagram dictionary taking forever compared to provided example

Tags: python-3.x

I made a program that was supposed to map out every anagram in a file full of words, it's not working out so well. I let it run for about 30 minutes(i7 processor) and it was only down to the M's. I realize this is probably because I used multiple loops, but short of copying the example(which would defeat the purpose) I'm not sure how to actually cut it down. as far as I can tell my program works, but not nearly fast enough for my satisfaction.

my code

```
fin=open('words.txt')

def histogram(s):
  l
  for c in s:
   d[c]=d.get(c, 0)+1
  return d

def anagram_check(word1, word2):
  flag=True
  #if word2!='aa':
    #print ('starting for ',word1, word2)
  for letter in word1:
    if letter not in word2:
      flag=False
  for letter in word2:
    if letter not in word1:
      flag=False
  if len(word1)!=len(word2):
    flag=False
  return flag  


def word_dict(wf, d):
  i=0
  for word in wf:
    if len(word.strip().lower())>=5:
      flag=True
      if d=={}:
        d[tuple(word.strip().lower())]=[]
      else:
        for k in d:
          if anagram_check(word, k)==True:
            flag=False
        if flag==True:
          d[tuple(word.strip().lower())]=[]
    i+=1
    if i>250 and i%250==0:
      print (len(d), ' ', word)
listofwords={}

word_dict(fin,listofwords)

def uses_all(s):
  l=list()
  global listofwords
  print ('starting checks for ',s)
  for i in range(len(listofwords)):
    word=listofwords[i]
    print (word)
    nef=in_both(word,s)
    print (nef)
    if nef==True:
      l.append(word)
      #print (l)
    #else:
      #print (word,' ',s, ' do not match')
  return l



def histomap():
  l=tuple()
  t=list()
  for word in fint:
    #print ('starting for ', word)
    l=uses_all(word)
    #print (l)
    t=t+(l)
    print (t)
  return t

print (listofwords)
```

the example (from think python2)

```
"""This module contains a code example related to

Think Python, 2nd Edition
by Allen Downey
http://thinkpython2.com

Copyright 2015 Allen Downey

License: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/
"""

from __future__ import print_function, division


def signature(s):
    """Returns the signature of this string.

    Signature is a string that contains all of the letters in order.

    s: string
    """
    # TODO: rewrite using sorted()
    t = list(s)
    t.sort()
    t = ''.join(t)
    return t


def all_anagrams(filename):
    """Finds all anagrams in a list of words.

    filename: string filename of the word list

    Returns: a map from each word to a list of its anagrams.
    """
    d = {}
    for line in open(filename):
        word = line.strip().lower()
        t = signature(word)

        # TODO: rewrite using defaultdict
        if t not in d:
            d[t] = [word]
        else:
            d[t].append(word)
    return d


def print_anagram_sets(d):
    """Prints the anagram sets in d.

    d: map from words to list of their anagrams
    """
    for v in d.values():
        if len(v) > 1:
            print(len(v), v)


def print_anagram_sets_in_order(d):
    """Prints the anagram sets in d in decreasing order of size.

    d: map from words to list of their anagrams
    """
    # make a list of (length, word pairs)
    t = []
    for v in d.values():
        if len(v) > 1:
            t.append((len(v), v))

    # sort in ascending order of length
    t.sort()

    # print the sorted list
    for x in t:
        print(x)


def filter_length(d, n):
    """Select only the words in d that have n letters.

    d: map from word to list of anagrams
    n: integer number of letters

    returns: new map from word to list of anagrams
    """
    res = {}
    for word, anagrams in d.items():
        if len(word) == n:
            res[word] = anagrams
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    anagram_map = all_anagrams('words.txt')
    print_anagram_sets_in_order(anagram_map)

    eight_letters = filter_length(anagram_map, 8)
    print_anagram_sets_in_order(eight_letters)
```

Comment: Rethink your method to test anagrams. Right now your method is to check if they share every letter. If you can speed up the method, everything will be sped up because that function is in the center of your program execution. For example, you can check if the two words are the same length first so you don't have to check every word. This would improve the performance a lot.

Comment: @u8y7541 thank you. I'll test it out hopefully later tonight